# XGBoost when classes are strings

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
_id    Points      Averages     Averages_2           Media               Rank 
a         324         858.2            NaN               0               Good
b         343         873.2      4.465e+06               1               Good
c         934         113.4            NaN               0                Bad
d         222         424.2            NaN               1                Bad
e         432         234.2      3.605e+06               1               Good
```

I want to predict the rank. Note that this is just a sample of a dataframe with 2000 rows and ca. 20 columns, but I tried to point out that there are columns, such as `Averages_2`, with lots of NaNs, and there are columns with values 0 or 1.

I did the following:

```
import xgboost as xgb

from sklearn import datasets

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder 
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import pandas as pd

data = 'C:\\me\\my_table.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(data)

cols_to_drop = ['_id']  #no need to write two lines if there's just one column to drop
                        #but since my original df is much bigger I used this to drop 
                        #multiple columns

df.drop(cols_to_drop, axis=1, inplace=True)

X = df.drop('Rank', axis=1)
y = df['Rank']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=5)

lc = LabelEncoder() 
lc = lc.fit(y) 
lc_y = lc.transform(y)

model = XGBClassifier() 
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = model.predict(X_test) 
predictions = [round(int(value)) for value in y_pred]
```

I get `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Good'` I thought encoding the classes would work but what else does one do when the classes are strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fails since your `y_pred` contains strings like `["Good","Bad"]`, thus your last line tries to call e.g `round(int("Good"))` which it, of course, cannot do (try call `print(y_pred[:5])` and see what it shows).

You are actually not using your label-encoder on neither your training or test-set (since you train it on `y` and never use it to transform `y_pred` nor `y_train`), and no need to when using XGboost, it handles the classes automatically.

Comment: Thank you! So I just deleted the last line and then checked the accuracy: `accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)`. It is 95.71%. Is my syntax correct to determine the accuracy of the predictions? Is there anything else I should pay attention to? Sorry, but I am very new to this. I tried eliminating some feature columns and re-run the model. It gives me the exact same accuracy.

Comment: If you want the accuracy, then yes

Answer (score 1):

Generally, all the machine learning models accept only the numerical values either in feature or target.

before split the data for train and test, you can do `LabelEncoder` or direct value changes like `df['rank'].replace({"Good":1,"Bad":0})`